# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

Tags: oracle, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

My Application uses JSF Primefaces 5.0, JDK 7, Oracle Database 12, Tomcat 8.
It works fine when I deploy my webapp war from within Eclipse on it's integrated Tomcat 8 server (all this happens on Maven build). But when I deploy manually the same war on Tomcat 8 server(using tomcat manager deploy UI) outside Eclipse IDE, I get the below error. Appreciate for any hints for this issue.

> Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol Error Code: 28040

My persistance.xml file is as below

```
<persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">       <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.myco.jpa.Agents</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@DBNC-01.MYCO.COM:1521/SCD.MYCO.COM"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="myname"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypw"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: My persistance.xml file is as below

Comment: Can you (and the person who upvoted) please, please, please explain why you think this is jsf, primefaces and tomcat related and *NOT* jpa or eclipselink?

Comment: You are probably using and outdated JDBC Driver and the URL should be `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//DBNC-01.MYCO.COM:1521/SCD.MYCO.COM` (note the `//` after the `@`)

Answer (score 3):

It worked fine with latest ojdbc driver jar downloaded from `http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html` No other changes needed.  Thank you for the hints!

Comment: this worked. Everything was working fine with ojdbc6, but suddenly it started giving me this error. Updgraded to ojdbc7

Answer (score 1):

this can happen with oracle 12.1,

Workaround: Set SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8 in the oracle/network/admin/sqlnet.ora file.